# Unable to install polyglot on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, polyglot, pyicu

I tried installing through `pip install polyglot` and got following error:

```
Collecting polyglot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/98/e24e2489114c5112b083714277204d92d372f5bbe00d5507acf40370edb9/polyglot-16.7.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: futures>=2.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from polyglot) (3.1.1)
Collecting PyICU>=1.8 (from polyglot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/15/0af20b540c828943b6ffea5677c86e908dcac108813b522adebb75c827c1/PyICU-2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Building PyICU 2.2 for ICU 63

    Could not configure CXXFLAGS with icu-config
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/20/4xrrmj050z10rqhlfn348q0m0000gn/T/pip-install-ZnSq3A/PyICU/setup.py", line 131, in <module>
        _cflags, ('--cxxflags', '--cppflags'), 'CXXFLAGS')
      File "/private/var/folders/20/4xrrmj050z10rqhlfn348q0m0000gn/T/pip-install-ZnSq3A/PyICU/setup.py", line 30, in configure_with_icu_config
        output = check_output(('icu-config',) + config_args).strip()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
        process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm getting exactly the same error when I try to install PyICU. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution here: https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu/issues/70#issuecomment-422806676

If you still get an `./common.h:86:10: fatal error: 'unicode/utypes.h' file not found` error please check out https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/34170#issuecomment-63192387 too.